Strong type check with "typedef" class
I'm working with Vulkan, and I have a class that manages a buffer allocated on the GPU.
To avoid mistakes, I want to differentiate an AllocatedBuffer from a buffer that is populated and is ready to use. Something such as AllocatedBuffer and DeviceBuffer.
In this case, both classes would be identical, except for the semantic. My renderer would create an AllocatedBuffer, populate it, and return a DeviceBuffer for external usage.
Is there any way that I can do using DeviceBuffer = AllocatedBuffer that would allow strong type checking? IOW, prevent functions with a DeviceBuffer parameter from being called with an AllocatedBuffer? I don't want to manage two classes that have to be identical, as this would be extra work and error prone.

If you own the original type, then you can realize a strong type with the help of a template parameter tag:
template<typename Tag>
class Buffer {
    /*...*/
};

using AllocatedBuffer = Buffer<struct AllocatedBufferTag>;
using DeviceBuffer = Buffer<struct DeviceBufferTag>;

Now you have two distinct and completely unrelated types with identical behavior.
You need to make sure that the tag types, which I declared inline above by prefixing with struct, are not used for any other purposes. Their names should be unique just for this use case. It may be better to put them into some namespace reserved for implementation details of your main namespace, so that there won't be accidental collisions.

Very interesting usage of templates. Can I still cast one type to another/explicit conversion? I'm ok with explicit conversions, as I want to construct a DeviceBuffer from an AllocatedBuffer.

@CaioVinícius Not automatically, no, but you can add some template<typename OtherTag> explicit Buffer(const Buffer<OtherTag>&); and/or template<typename OtherTag> explicit Buffer(Buffer<OtherTag>&&); constructor to the template where you can then define the behavior for explicit conversions in the copy and move cases respectively.

@CaioVinícius You generally won't get around a copy/move being made though. Depending on how you implemented these buffers that may be cheap or not. Depending on how exactly the class is implemented, you may (or may not) be allowed to use std::start_lifetime_as to get a DeviceBuffer from a AllocatedBuffer in-place without a copy/move.

I see, so there may be the disadvantage of creating a new object. Thankfully these classes are really cheap, they only store handles. I will check std::start_lifetime_as also. Thanks.

@CaioVinícius Yes, as long as there is still an indirection to the actual memory instead of it being embedded into the object itself, there shouldn't be any problem. Otherwise it becomes a bit tricky. std::start_lifetime_as should be used only very carefully. You can easily cause undefined behavior and the results will depend on class layout guarantees that you must assure/verify yourself. It would be a last resort if you need to embed the buffer's memory directly into the object.

@CaioVinícius Also, as a side note: An explicit constructor is still usable in direct-initialization, so the user will be able to write DeviceBuffer a(f()); where f returns an AllocatedBuffer. I think that isn't particularly safe. Better would be to make the constructor private and friend it to be used only by one function that the user has to call explicit to make a DeviceBuffer from a AllocatedBuffer, so that any such site will be clearly identified, e.g. by DeviceBuffer a = DeviceBufferFromAllocatedBuffer(f());, instead of relying on explicit casts.

fwiw, decltype([](){}) is a unique type. It can be used to define the aliases and after that there is no way to accidentally use a tag that has already been used. If needed the tags can still be deduced from a given instantiation

@463035818_is_not_an_ai That's going to be a different type in each translation unit then, probably not intended here.
